# Symfony2, Wordpress and Nginx: How should configuration file look like

Tags: wordpress, symfony, nginx

I have a project set up on Nginx running on Symfony2 with Wordpress blog in it. Wordpress blog is inside web/ in Symfony2. Some things on the blog doesn't work (for example infinite 302 on wp-admin and some CSS issues). Can someone show me how proper config file for this setup should look like? 
Mine looks like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name project.com *.project.com;
  return 301 https://www.project.com$request_uri;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html/project.com/web;

  error_log /var/log/nginx/project.error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/project.access.log;

  client_max_body_size 12M;

  # strip app.php/ prefix if it is present
  #rewrite ^/app\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

  location / {
    index app.php;
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    if ($http_host ~ "^[^.]+\.[^.]+$"){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ https:%1://www.$http_host$request_uri redirect;
    }
  }

  location @rewriteapp {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
  }

  # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
  location ~ .php {
    #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  HTTPS              off;
  }
}

server {
    listen 443;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/www.project.com/project-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/www.project.com/project.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !MEDIUM";
    ssl_dhparam dh4096.pem;

    server_name project.com *.project.com;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/project.com/web;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/project.error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project.access.log;

    client_max_body_size 12M;

    # strip app.php/ prefix if it is present
    rewrite ^/app\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

    location / {
      index app.php;
      try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
      if ($http_host ~ "^[^.]+\.[^.]+$"){
          rewrite ^(.*)$ https:%1://www.$http_host$request_uri redirect;
      }
    }

    location /blog/wp-admin/ {
      index index.php;
    #  #try_files $uri @rewriteindex;
    #  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    #location @rewriteindex {
    #  rewrite ^(.*)$ /blog/wp-admin/index.php/$1 last;
    #}

    location @rewriteapp {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ .php {
      #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param  HTTPS              off;
    }

    location .(js|jpg|png|css)$ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/project.com/web;
        expires 30d;
    }
}
```

This config file is just a mess. It might be better just to start from scratch but I'm not sure how I should handle the Wordpress part inside web/blog/

Answer (score 0):

location ~ /blog {
                proxy_pass http://your_wp_server_url;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
and define in a new site enabled file in nginx the server for wordpress:

```
server{
 server_name your_wp_server_url;
 root path_to_wordpress;
 .
 . 
 .

}
```

Comment: I can't test it right now but will it work for blog url like this https://www.example.com/blog/ ?